# Inherit default Button style

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to inherit and alter the style of the default button but cannot figure out how.

Using:

```
<Style x:Key="MyBasicButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"></Style>
```

does not work, it says the `"Type" cannot be used in Windows Store App project`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="InheritedStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks it works - nice approach to define a BaseStyle and inherit from it...in BaseStyle I've pasted the content of the default button style (took it from "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709909.aspx")